# Can you get a reply from a HTTPS site using the Ping command?

Tags: http, ping, https

I tried using the `ping` command on a `https` page, but the message says that `ping` could not find the host. Is there some issue regarding `ping` and `https`?

Comment: Short answer: Ping and HTTPS have *nothing* in common. [Ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) is a low level network tool whereas [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) is an application layer protocol (or rather, an URI scheme).

Comment: If you want to test that you ssl site is responding correctly use openssl this way: "openssl s_client  -connect google.com:443"  Then you can issue a GET command followed by two presses on the return key like this: "GET / HTTP/1.1"

Comment: In case anybody ended up here looking for a ping-like tool for https, I just wrote one: https://github.com/voutasaurus/sup

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer to your question (Can you get a reply from a HTTPS site using the Ping command?) is Yes, you can, as long as [ICMP replies are enabled on the HTTPS site provider.](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/79633-disabling-icmp-echo-requests-windows-firewall.html) However, it has nothing to do with HTTP or HTTPS:

[Ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) will use [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) protocol, it belongs to TCP/IP [Internet Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Layer), which is a lower layer than [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) or [HTTPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) (from [Application Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Layer)):

> Ping operates by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo request packets to the target host and waiting for an ICMP response. In the process it measures the time from transmission to reception (round-trip time)[1](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/79633-disabling-icmp-echo-requests-windows-firewall.html) and records any packet loss. The results of the test are printed in form of a statistical summary of the response packets received, including the minimum, maximum, and the mean round-trip times, and sometimes the standard deviation of the mean.

You can test with "cmd" (Windows Start button / type cmd in the search box, open "cmd.exe"), then with ping:

```
ping www.hotmail.com
```

If you try to ping a HTTP URL, such it follows:

```
ping http://www.hotmail.com
```

You will get the same error that you would get when trying to ping a HTTPS based URL:

```
ping https://www.hotmail.com
```

(An error something like that ping cant reach the requested address will appear on both attempts).

Answer (score 24):

`ping` works at a much lower level than HTTP or HTTPS, and only accepts *hostnames*, not URLs. For example:

```
ping www.google.com
```

Answer (score 14):

[tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) - simulate "ping" over tcp by establishing a connection to network hosts. tcping at application level will send SYN, waiting for ACK, closing with FIN ACK

```
C:\>tcping google.com 443

Probing 87.106.83.127:443/tcp - Port is open - time=19.787ms
Probing 87.106.83.127:443/tcp - Port is open - time=20.487ms
Probing 87.106.83.127:443/tcp - Port is open - time=24.494ms
Control-C

Ping statistics for 87.106.83.127:443
     3 probes sent.
     3 successful, 0 failed.
Approximate trip times in milli-seconds:
     Minimum = 19.787ms, Maximum = 24.494ms, Average = 21.589ms
```

Answer (score 3):

You can issue a HEAD request with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect github.com:443 <<eof
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: github.com

eof
```

Note that you can also use "HTTP/2", but be careful because some servers
(e.g. github.com) do not support it.